# The datagridview scrolls up

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

My datagridview automatically scrolls up whenever i scroll down. I don't know why.

I tried to search every possible solution but I can't solve it.
Is there a property i should change or what?

Comment: You will have to show & tell us more! This will never happen by itself. Meaning: __You__ have put some code somewhere, that does it; how could __we__ know..?? Do you have some automatic refresh triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. But if you want to scroll down in DataGridView (bottom of DataGridView), you have to do this:

```
int Count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, Count-1];
```